# How can I use animation for refresh control?

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift4, uirefreshcontrol, lottie

I want to use Lottie animation for refresh control in table view instead of using activity indicator or label. Is refresh control prevent this type of customization, or do I need something else? 
(Lottie is a library which allows ability to Swift for playing Adobe After Effect animations.)

Comment: You can do that. Take a look at this tutorial: https://www.appcoda.com/custom-pull-to-refresh/

Comment: It seems very complicated

Comment: Well yeah... what you are wanting to do is a complicated thing.  There are plenty of third-party libraries that do the custom refresh control for you if you would rather not do the work.  Check out all of these third party pull-to-refresh options: https://github.com/vsouza/awesome-ios#pull-to-refresh

Answer (score 1):

How to use `Lottie` animation in your `UIRefreshControl`:

```
let refreshControl = UIRefreshControl()
let loadingView = LOTAnimationView(name: "<- whatever your animation... ->")
loadingView.play()
loadingView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
loadingView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
loadingView.loopAnimation = true
refreshControl.addSubview(loadingView)
loadingView <-> constraint layout to <-> refreshControl
refreshControl.tintColor = .clear
```

you can also subclass from UIRefreshControl if you use it multiple times in your app...

Enjoy.